# How do I split file on batches using powershell

Tags: sql, powershell

How do I split file on batches using powershell?

I have a sql post deploy file with multiple batches. Below is example of my postDeployment.sql file.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'StoredProc') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
BEGIN
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[StoredProc]
END

** GO **

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[StoredProc]
    @nodeId int = 0 

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
END

**GO**

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'StoredProc') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
BEGIN
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[StoredProc]
END

**GO**

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[StoredProc]     
    @nodeId int = 0 
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
END
```

$_

**I need to execute each batch by it self. Shile spliting on highlighted ** GO ****

My PS Command is as follows (not working correctly):

```
function GetSqlBatchesFromString($file)
{
    $buffer = new-object System.Text.StringBuilder
    switch -regex -file $file {

        "^\s*GO[\s\d]*$" 
            { 
               # $__ returns go
                $buffer.ToString(); 
                $buffer.Length = 0;
            }
        default 
            { 
            $temp = $buffer.AppendLine($_);
            } 
        }

    $buffer.ToString();
}

function ExecuteBatch($batch)
{
Write-Host "Batch part ==== start"
Write-Host $batch
Write-Host "Batch part ==== end"   
}

 GetSqlBatchesFromString "D:\PostDeployment.sql" | % { ExecuteBatch $__}
```

Comment: Follow-up question that asks for more robust processing that rules out false positives from the word `GO` appearing in quoted strings and comments: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70161661/45375

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution but it does not cover all cases like GO inside of sql:

```
$file = "D:\PostDeployment.sql"

  $SQLCommandText = @(Get-Content -Path $file) # loads content
    foreach($SQLString in  $SQLCommandText) 
    { 

        if($SQLString -ne "go") # if string is not equal to go then add it to existing string
        { 
            #Preparation of SQL packet 
            $SQLPacket += $SQLString + "`n" 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            Write-Host "---------------------------------------------" 
            Write-Host "Executed SQL packet:" 
            Write-Host $SQLPacket 

            $SQLPacket = ""  # clear up sql string
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

this:

```
$a = ( [system.io.file]::ReadAllText( "c:\file.sql" ) -split '(?:\bGO\b)' ) | 
% { $_ + "`r`nGO" }
```

create an array whit batch then you can try:

```
$a | % { ExecuteBatch $__}
```

Comment: I have put this into my script, but I do not get any results at all

Comment: just noticed that I have been running old version of powershell.. now I am on 3 hopefully the command will still work

Comment: Hey, how can we avoid splitting the GO text that are with in single quotes? I have a similar problem and I wanted to test if this works for a SQL file that has content something like  SELECT 'Testing GO if this gets split'; GO SELECT 'Normal' and noticed this splits the above into "SELECT 'Testing" as one batch and  "if this gets split';" as next batch and third batch as "SELECT 'Normal'" @cpoDesign

Answer (score 0):

```
function Get-SqlBatchesFromFile {
    param($file)

    $accumulate = @()

    foreach($line in (get-content $file)){
        if($line -match "^\*\*\s?GO") {        
            $accumulate -join "`r`n"
            $accumulate = @()
        } else {
            $accumulate+=$line
        }
    }
}

filter Invoke-ExecuteBatch {
    Write-Host "Batch part ==== start"
    Write-Host $_
    Write-Host "Batch part ==== end"   
}

Get-SqlBatchesFromString  C:\temp\test.sql | Invoke-ExecuteBatch
```

Comment: @() is how you create an empty array