# Splitting SQL file/String into batches using PowerShell exclude split when content is in single quotes

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm splitting my SQL file into batches based on the String **GO**.
I took stackoverflow thread [How do I split file on batches using powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875643/how-do-i-split-file-on-batches-using-powershell/18875995#18875995) as reference
And noticed this regex doesn't work for few scenarios

- If the go is found in single quotes the string gets split. (I
  want to avoid the split for any text that are inside single quotes)
- And another scenario is when I use go on Declare statement like
  Declare @go

I'm not familiar with regex patterns. So, I tried to search some online documentation on regex and came up with the pattern to find anything within single quotes and how to ignore the @go in file when splitting. Below are the regex

- **('([\s\S]*?)')** - gets me the string that is with in single quotes, but I'm not sure how to add this match to exclude to current regex pattern
- **(?<![\S])**(?:\bGO\b) - Can avoid splitting when any non Whitespace char is before the GO string that took care of @go in below sql file

**SQL file content:**

```
select * from testTbl; GO
select * from testTbl2;
GO

Declare @go varchar(15) = 'IGo test'

select @go

GO

SELECT 'go', '   go  ', 'asdv Igo asdsad',
'
go
'

GO

create table #Temp
(
    IdGo int, 
    GoId Varchar(50)
)

select * from #Temp

drop table #Temp

GO
```

PowerShell script line:

```
$batches = ( $scriptData -split "(?:\bGO\b)" ) | % { $_ + "`r`nGO" }
```

Note: var `$scriptData` has the SQL file content in it.

Is this a correct approach or how can we exclude the split when the string is with in single quotes? Is there any cleaner approach to do this?

FYI: I'll update the other thread answer, Once I can figure out the solution to this. Or I'm happy to update the other thread and delete this if any one feels it is a duplicate.

**Updated:** Desired output:

```
select * from testTbl;
GO
select * from testTbl2;
GO
Declare @go varchar(15) = 'IGo test' select @go
GO
SELECT 'go', ' go ', 'asdv Igo asdsad','go'
GO
create table #Temp ( IdGo int, GoId Varchar(50) ) select * from #Temp drop table #Temp
GO
```

Comment: It might be worth adding what your desired output would be to give others a better perspective of your need. In addition, is the __`GO`__ you want to target __always__ uppercase?

Comment: The GO can be upper/lower case. @SantiagoSquarzon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To robustly parse your input into batches, **you need a *language parser*** that can reliably identify syntactic elements - [regexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) are *not* sophisticated enough to model the grammar of your input.

In the absence of a T-SQL parser,<sup>[1]</sup> **you can *probably* get away with *PowerShell*'s own language parser**, [`[System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser), given that there are high-level commonalities between the two languages, so it should be able to identify isolated, non-`@`-prefixed `GO` tokens in your input:

**Caveat** re **commment support**:

- Because T-SQL's comment constructs differ from PowerShell, using **the PowerShell parser would yield *false positives* for (isolated) `GO` substrings *inside comments***.
- The solution below therefore uses ***regex*-based *preprocessing* that *removes all comments*** (with additional effort involving a post-processing step, the comments could be preserved), but this isn't fully robust and relies on the following **assumptions**:

  - No comment-like constructs appear inside *quoted* strings.
  - Block quotes (`/* ... */`) aren't *nested*.
    (With a more sophisticated regex using [balancing group definitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#balancing_group_definition) you may be able to overcomes this particular limitation).

```sh
# Get the file's content and preprocess it by *removing comments*,
# to prevent GO instances inside them from yielding false positives.
# CAVEAT: This isn't fully robust, but may work well enough in practice.
#         See the notes above this code snippet.
$fileContent = (Get-Content -Raw t.txt) -replace '(?m)^\s*--.*' -replace '(?s)/\*.*?\*/'

# Parse the file content into an AST (Abstract Syntax Tree),
# as if it were PowerShell code.
$ast = [System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseInput($fileContent, [ref] $null, [ref] $null)

# Get all locations - in terms of line and column number - of isolated,
# unquoted GO tokens.
$locations = 
  $ast.FindAll({ $args[0].Extent.Text -eq 'go' }, $false) | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Extent |
      Select-Object StartLineNumber, StartColumnNumber -Unique

# Split the file content into batches by the locations of the 
# isolated, unquoted GO tokens, resulting in an array of strings
# each representing a batch, stored in $batches.
$thisBatch = ''
$lineNo = $locNdx = 0
[string[]] $batches =
  $fileContent -split '\r?\n' | ForEach-Object {
    if (++$lineNo -eq $locations[$locNdx].StartLineNumber) {
      $fromCol = 0
      do {
        $thisBatch + $_.Substring($fromCol, $locations[$locNdx].StartColumnNumber - $fromCol + 2 - 1)
        $thisBatch = ''
        $fromCol = $locations[$locNdx].StartColumnNumber + 2 - 1
      } while ($locations[++$locNdx].StartLineNumber -eq $lineNo)
      if ($fromCol -lt $_.Length) {
        $thisBatch =  $_.Substring($fromCol) + "`n"
      }
    } else {
      $thisBatch += "$_`n"
    }
  }
# If the last batch wasn't terminated with a GO, we must add it now.
# Remove + "`nGO" if you don't want to append a terminating GO.
if ($thisBatch.Trim()) { $batches += $thisBatch + "`nGO" }

# Diagnostic output, to show the resulting batches:
$batches -join "`n-----------------`n"
```

Output of the above, based on your sample input:

```
select * from testTbl; GO
-----------------
select * from testTbl2;
GO
-----------------

Declare @go varchar(15) = 'IGo test'

select @go

GO
-----------------

SELECT 'go', '   go  ', 'asdv Igo asdsad',
'
go
'

GO
-----------------

create table #Temp
(
    IdGo int, 
    GoId Varchar(50)
)

select * from #Temp

drop table #Temp

GO
```

**Note**:

- No attempt was made to condense each batch into a *single-line* representation, but that shouldn't be a problem.
- The code also handles multiple batches *on a single line* correctly, such as the two complete and the one incomplete batch in the following example:

  ```sh
  select * from testTbl0;GO select * from testTbl1 GO Declare @go varchar(15) = 'IGo test'
  ```
- Also, a final batch that happens not to be terminated with `GO` is included.

---

<sup>[1] Note: "GO is not a Transact-SQL statement; it is a command recognized by the `sqlcmd` and `osql` utilities and SQL Server Management Studio Code editor." - see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go)

The docs also state that a "Transact-SQL statement cannot occupy the same line as a GO command.", which would make the first sample batch in the question technically invalid, but Raj (the OP) reports that it works nonetheless.</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm okay to not condense each batch into a single-line. I have tested with above code and getting the expected result except for one case, when the file has something like on same line (select * from testTbl;GO select * from testTbl2  GO  Declare @go varchar(15) = 'IGo test'). The processing stops after finding the first GO statement and result is shown as (select * from testTbl;GO) and never processed remaining content in file

Comment: @RajK according to MS Docs, the syntax should be `GO [count] -- (EOL)` are you sure `GO SELECT..` is a valid syntax?

Comment: Good point, @SantiagoSquarzon. Based on that, even the first sample input line currently in the question isn't valid. To [quote the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go): "A Transact-SQL statement cannot occupy the same line as a GO command. "

Comment: @mklement0 having code fixing syntactical errors should be out the question, right? ;)

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I agree with you, I've checked the doc now. But I tried to use this statement on SQL server to check if it is a valid and getting executed without error on SQL server (SELECT * FROM testTbl GO SELECT * FROM testTbl2) both statement are on same line. Looking at this user can still send a file with Select statements on the same line that can have a GO in between

Comment: @mklement0 Yes, that correct. They are not part of the line. Sorry for the confusion, not sure how to differentiate the line so I've used ( and )

Comment: @RajK, please see my update, which should handle the multiple-batches-on-one-line case correctly. As for formatting in comments: see https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting - in short: you can only use _inline_ code formatting (`\`...\``) with no support for line breaks, and you cannot _double_ `\`` instances - use `\\`` to embed `\``.

Comment: @mklement0 This is working great! the last statement is ignored though the result looks like `select * from testTbl0 GO
-----------------
 select * from testTbl1 GO` . The `Declare @go varchar(15) = 'IGo test'` is not going into $batches

Comment: @RajK, my assumption was that each batch was terminated with `GO`, but please see my update, which now includes a final batch even if it lacks that terminator.

Comment: @mklement0 what does wva means on the do while loop code `do {
        $lineNo | wva` . I'm getting term not recognized on powershell

Comment: @RajK - Oops! Sorry about that - that was left over from my debugging. Simply remove that line (I've also updated the answer).

Comment: @mklement0 Great! this is working. I'll go ahead and accept your answer. Just a quick other thing, how can we avoid the GO in any of the comment section(single/block comments). Something like below `-- GO
--sadsad
/*GO */
--asdasd
/*
 GO
*/
Select * from testTbl

GO`. This breaks the GO in comment section too.

Comment: Thanks, @RajK. Please see my update, which now handles comments, but with limitations - note the assumptions made (listed above the code).